# Spotipy: 'Index out of range' when trying to retrieve album_ids so that I can get their release dates

Tags: python, spotipy

I am working with this data, which I extracted from a public playlist and shows all of the number 1's since 1953 with their audio features: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StanWaldron/StanWaldron.github.io/main/FinalData.csv

I am now trying to loop through and find their album ids so that I can retrieve their release date and plot their audio features against other time series data, using this code:

```
def find_album_release(name):
    album_ids = []
    for x in name:
        results = sp.search(q="album:" + x, type="album")
        if not results["albums"]["items"]:
            return []
        album_id = results['albums']['items'][0]['uri']
        album_ids.append(album_id)
        print(album_id)
    return album_ids


final = pd.read_csv('FinalData.csv')
albumlist = final['album']
finalalbums = find_album_release(albumlist)
```

It works for the first 7 and then returns nothing. Without the if statement, it returns that the index is out of range. I have tested the 8th element by hard coding in its album name and it returns the correct result, this is the same for the next 4 in the list so it isn't an issue with the searching of these album names. I have played around with the lists but I am not entirely sure what is out of range of what.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 8th row album name has single quotes in its name (`Don't Stop Me Eatin'`). I tried to remove the quotes and it worked. Maybe you should check what characters are allowed in the query parameters.

```
def find_album_release(name):
    album_ids = []
    for x in name:
        x = x.replace("'", "") # Remove the quotes from album name
        results = sp.search(q="album:" + x, type="album")
        ....
    ....


final = pd.read_csv('FinalData.csv')
albumlist = final['album']
finalalbums = find_album_release(albumlist)
```

The output for me:

```
spotify:album:31lHUoHC3P6BRFzKYLyRJO
spotify:album:6s84u2TUpR3wdUv4NgKA2j
spotify:album:4OyzQQJHEfKXRfyN4QyLR7
spotify:album:2Hjcfw8zHN4dJDZJGOzLd6
spotify:album:1zEBi4O4AaY5M55dUcUp3z
spotify:album:0Hi8bTOS35xZM0zZ6S89hT
spotify:album:5GGIgiGtxIgcVJQnsKQW94
spotify:album:3rLjiJI34bHFNIFqeK3y9s
spotify:album:6q1MiYTIE28nFzjkvLLt0I
spotify:album:61ulfFSmmxMhc2wCdmdMkN
spotify:album:3euz4vS7ezKGnNSwgyvKcd
spotify:album:1pFaEu56zqpzSviJc3htZN
spotify:album:4PTxbJPI4jj0Kx8hwr1v0T
spotify:album:2ogiazbrNEx0kQHGl5ZBTQ
spotify:album:5glfCPECXSHzidU6exW8wO
spotify:album:1XMw3pBrYeXzNXZXc84DNw
spotify:album:623PL2MBg50Br5dLXC9E9e
spotify:album:4TqgXMSSTwP3RCo3MMSR6t
spotify:album:3xIwVbGJuAcovYIhzbLO3J
spotify:album:3h2xv1tJgDnJZGy5Roxs5A
spotify:album:66xP0vUo8to8ALVpkyKc41
spotify:album:6XcYTEonLIpg9NpAbJnqrC
spotify:album:5sXSHscDjBez8VF20cSyad
spotify:album:6pQZPa398NswBXGYyqHH7y
spotify:album:0488X5veBK6t3vSmIiTDJY
```